# Google Calendar API --> How can I make the useraccount from which I retrieve Events, variable?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm currently working with the Google Calendar API.
I retrieve a list of EVENTS from the user's calendar, but at the moment the account of the user is given in my code.
I wan't to make this variable (It should retrieve EVENTS from the account you select).

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Tryout for Google Calendar');
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('myid');
$client->setClientSecret('mysecret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/gcal/done.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('mykey');

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
$minCheck = date(DATE_ATOM);

$eventList = $cal->events->listEvents("phpkay@gmail.com", array('singleEvents' =>                      'true', 'timeMin' => $minCheck));

  print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($eventList, true) . "</pre>";


$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}

?>
```

This is the part where I set the useraccount, namely: "phpkay@gmail.com"

```
$eventList = $cal->events->listEvents("phpkay@gmail.com", array('singleEvents' => 'true', 'timeMin' => $minCheck));
```

How can I retrieve the selected useraccount (the user gets a screen where he can select one of the Google accounts he owns to use for this APP) and use this instead of the set "phpkay@gmail.com"-account?

Sorry if my question is unclear, I have no clue how to phrase this in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the OAuth 2.0 API. Just include:

```
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users
```

in your list of OAuth scopes and then make an authenticated GET request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

this will return the email address of the authenticated user. You can try this out in the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get?_h=1&)